# Query with subquery and Max without success

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have database structure.

```
/****** [Customers]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customers](
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NOT NULL,
    [CompanyName] [nvarchar](40) NOT NULL,
    [ContactName] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [ContactTitle] [nvarchar](30) NULL,
    [Address] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [City] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Region] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [PostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [Country] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [Phone] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
    [Fax] [nvarchar](24) NULL,
);

/****** [Orders]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Orders](
    [OrderID] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [CustomerID] [nchar](5) NULL,
    [EmployeeID] [int] NULL,
    [OrderDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [RequiredDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShippedDate] [datetime] NULL,
    [ShipVia] [int] NULL,
    [Freight] [money] NULL,
    [ShipName] [nvarchar](40) NULL,
    [ShipAddress] [nvarchar](60) NULL,
    [ShipCity] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipRegion] [nvarchar](15) NULL,
    [ShipPostalCode] [nvarchar](10) NULL,
    [ShipCountry] [nvarchar](15) NULL
);

/****** [Orders Details]    ******/
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order Details](
    [OrderID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [ProductID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [UnitPrice] [money] NOT NULL 
);
```

I need to create a query that returns: OrderID, OrderDate, CompanyName and Total Order.

I am trying with the following query, but it is wrong and do not know what could be done differently to achieve the expected result.

Query used:

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDate, CompanyName,
       (SELECT OrderID, SUM([UnitPrice])
        FROM [Order Details] GROUP BY OrderID HAVING COUNT(OrderID)=1) AS TOTAL
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```

This giving the error:

> Message 116, Level 16, State 1, line 10 Only one expression can be
>   specified in the selection list when the subquery is not introduced
>   with exists.

I do not know how to fix, could someone please help me.

Comment: `(SELECT SUM([UnitPrice]) FROM [Order Details]  WHERE OrderID = Orders.OrderID) AS TOTAL`

Answer (score 0):

As you want to total of each order id so need to put order id on subquery and have to remove `orderid` from subquery selection 
try like below

```
SELECT Orders.OrderID, OrderDate, CompanyName,
       (SELECT SUM([UnitPrice])
        FROM [Order Details] d
       WHERE d.OrderID = Orders.OrderID
      GROUP BY d.OrderID           
       ) AS TOTAL
FROM Orders
INNER JOIN Customers ON Customers.CustomerID = Orders.CustomerID
INNER JOIN [Order Details] ON [Order Details].OrderID = Orders.OrderID
```

Comment: redundant `GROUP BY d.OrderID` and, of course, join to details in the end.

Answer (score 0):

You can join a subquery, in which the sum per order is calculated.

```
SELECT o.[orderid],
       o.[orderdate],
       c.[companyname],
       d.[total]
       FROM [orders] o
            LEFT JOIN [customers] c
                      ON c.[customerid] = o.[customerid]
            LEFT JOIN (SELECT d.[orderid],
                              sum(d.[unitprice]) [total]
                              FROM [order details] d
                              GROUP BY d.[orderid]) d
                      ON d.[orderid] = o.[orderid];
```